# Dialog box tells me there's a missing driver when installing 64-bit version of Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, drivers

I'm trying to install Windows 7 64-bit on my computer (ASUS P6T Deluxe V2, one 80GB HDD and two 1 TB HDDs). When I'm supposed to select whether I want to Upgrade or do a Custom install, I get a dialog box telling me:

> Load Driver
>
> A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing. If you have a driver floppy disk, CD, DVD, or USB flash drive, please insert it now.
>
> Note: If the Windows installation media is in the CD/DVD drive, you can safely remove it for this step.

I've tried to reach this step using a 32-bit installation disc, but that doesn't generate this message at all. Through the command windows (shift-F10) I can reach all of my drives, including my optical drive, without any problems--so what kind of device driver is it the installation wants? I've tried all the obvious drivers on the CD that followed my motherboard, but I can't seem to find the right one. The problem is that I don't know what device I'm supposed to load the drivers for in the first place.

Can anyone help me?

**Edit**: It turned out that my downloaded image was corrupted. I borrowed a DVD from a friend of mine, which worked!

Comment: Do I really need to install drivers for my DVD-station?

Comment: According to http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistasetup/thread/4d906f85-7650-4eff-8bd2-13ec2b0bd2ae, the error message that you are receiving is very generic and likely doesn't actually mean that you need DVD drive drivers.  It could mean that you need ATAPI drivers or SATA drivers.

Comment: The only two drivers I am able to load is ASUSs EPUsix-engine (something to do with powersaving) and TurbV (something with OC-ing). The "ICH10R AHCI/RAID Driver Disk for Windows 32/64bit 7." and "Intel(R) Matrix Storage Manager V8.9.0.1023 for Windows 7 and Windows 64bit 7.(WHQL)" doesn't help me at all...

Comment: Best typo ever in the OP. Anyone else catch it?

Comment: Just to make certain, did you extract the contents of the Matrix Storage Manager archive to removable media using the -a option?  I just want to make sure since the Windows 7 installer won't read the compressed archive.

Comment: Yes, I extracted the files from the archive (I tried to select them manually as well).

Comment: The most common solutions I've seen on Google for this motherboard involve 1) corrupted download or dvd burn (by far, the most common), and 2) updating the DVD drive firmware.

Since you already tried making a new DVD, maybe you should try calculating the MD5 for your downloaded image and comparing that value with others on the internet.

Comment: You're right Chrisbux, the download was corrupt.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this exact error message, and it was caused by some sort of error on the DVD that I burned (I had burned the DVD at the fastest supported speed).

I solved it by using a new blank DVD and burning the ISO at the slowest speed that the DVD burner supported.

I think when I burned the original DVD, it verified correctly.  For some reason, it seems that the Windows 7 installer is more sensitive to media errors.

Comment: It didn't work me, unfortunately :-(

Comment: Take a look at http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistasetup/thread/4d906f85-7650-4eff-8bd2-13ec2b0bd2ae.  In that case, the user had to load ATAPI drivers for his PATA DVD drive and SATA drivers for his AHCI/RAID setup.

Comment: Maybe calculating the MD5 of the image that you downloaded will help you confirm that the download wasn't corrupted.  I'd list the MD5 sum here, but I'm not sure of the exact version that you have.

Comment: I just tried a fourth disc, which I got from a friend of mine, and that one worked. I guess my image was corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Get a USB DVD-drive and try installing from that. If you can't or it doesn't work:

Put the installfiles on a USB flash drive, that way you shouldn't have to load any drivers.. If you need to know how to do this, Google (with Bing :)) for "Windows 7 install from usb" or something, should be many guides that show you how to do this..

Have fun! :)

Comment: It turned out my image was corrupted, I tried installing with a USB flash drive, but it didn't work. Thanks anyway!