# Installing Windows 7 on a Asus Maximus VIII Ranger motherboard fails

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I have Asus Maximus VIII Ranger as my motherboard and I'm trying to install Windows 7 on it, with little success.

My processor is the new i7-6700K if that matters.

I'm getting my USB devices to work during the install, but it still complains that it cannot find the optical drive drivers. What's quite interesting is that I don't have one connected to my computer, since my old one was still IDE and the new motherboard doesn't quite support that.

Now apparently this is quite the general error message when some drivers are missing. Is there any way to find out what drivers are missing?

I made a boot-able USB install stick with the Windows USB/DVD Download Tool.

The user manual for the motherboard had some guides, but they dealt with the USB 3.0 driver issues only.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/44160/dialog-box-tells-me-theres-a-missing-driver-when-installing-64-bit-version-of-w

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/245368/installing-windows-7-ultimate-64-bit-mentions-a-missing-cd-dvd-driver?lq=1

Comment: Hmm, It has a ps/2 port, for whatever reason, maybe i should try that. Now only to find a keyboard that goes with that :)

Comment: It didn't work, i downloaded NTLite to embed drivers into the win7 installer. I downloaded all of the drivers for the MB and embedded them into the installer.

Comment: this is USB 3.x issue. Win7 doesn't hae native USB 3.0/3.1 support.Also embedd the USB 3.0/3.1 drivers to the boot.wim or use an USB 2.0 port

Comment: I used a PS/2 keyboard and the port should have been USB 2.0 since the my USB keyboard worked from that slot on a previous install attempt. I'll get an optical drive and try installing without any USB devices next.

Answer (score 0):

I did it.

No USB devices can be plugged in while Windows 7 is being installed, **none**.

I needed to buy a new optical drive, since my external USB one could not be plugged in. A USB flash drive wouldn't work either, even though the install did load from it.

Also, a PS/2 keyboard is necessary. What's great is that the MB I have, has one.

Comment: Does it work after the fact? I wonder if its some wierdness with windows 7, but that's still new/common enough that it should have been tested.

Comment: Yes, but for whatever reason I need to re-plug my keyboard every time I want to log in, mouse works fine.