# Windows 10 installation failure due to missing driver

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, usb, drivers

I once installed windows 10 from USB that I had. Then for a reason, I need a clean install of it. Now when I'm using the USB I'm getting a response saying "A media driver your computer needs is missing. This coould be a DVD, USB or Hard Disk driver. If ou have a CD/DVD or USB flash drive with the driver on it, please insert it now."

It's an ASUS X555LA-XX688D laptop

[image]

What is causing this issue and how do I resolve this?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/44160/dialog-box-tells-me-theres-a-missing-driver-when-installing-64-bit-version-of-w?rq=1 and http://superuser.com/questions/83228/required-cd-dvd-device-driver-missing-while-installing-windows-7?rq=1 and http://superuser.com/questions/959879/windows-10-installation-a-media-driver-your-computer-needs-is-missing?rq=1

Comment: I'm sorry to say none of those helped.

Comment: Find that hard to believe

Comment: Did the accepted answer work for you? If not, then why did you accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem a few times while installing Windows 10 on different machine, but today I found a solution that I could test and confirm several times.

In my case:

- I hit Cancel on this dialog
- removed pendrive
- canceled installation (return to 'Install now' screen)
- installed pendrive in the **other** USB port
- clicked 'Install now' button

The screen didn't appear now and installation runs perfectly (well, almost, but that's a different story).

I hope you can confirm that it worked for you as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
Turned out that it has some issue with USB. Whichever USB you start with, you have to switch over to another one and then you can continue.

Comment: Having exact same issue but your solution doesn't do it for us...

Comment: This does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was the ISO:

Something happened to the ISO while moving to a Windows Machine:

I usually work on a Linux machine, but to create a Bootable USB, I prefer to use Rufus (because there isn't a functional Tool on Linux to create a Bootable Windows 10 USB).
So, i get an official Windows ISO, copied to an USB Stick and moved to an Windows PC to create an Bootable USB Stick with Rufus. Now i got the mentioned Error.

I verified the Hash Value of the ISO immediately after the Download, and after i've copied to the other Windows computer with the Official Hash Values of Microsoft.

on my Linux System, with bash:

```
sha256sum windows.iso
```

Result:

A09D5C6B5F4E82C1B51314D33420AE4EB1BDDE1C75C036258EF439A4F0F5AE6D

on the Windows System (after copied), with Powershell:

```
Get-FileHash windows.iso
```

Result:

6B5E33A0CD10625795AFE7314B223DD3CED2F229AA99725762C5AE58DA03565B

The Hash Values where different. Although nothing has changed. (The Values above are just examples and differs from your Hash)

I believe that is why the error arises. (Maybe this has something to do with secure boot?)

I've solved this by packing the ISO in a TAR file, before i transfer the File to the USB Stick (to move it to the Windows System).
After TAR extract on Windows, the Hash Value are the same and the Windows Installation Error are gone.

Lessons learned : TAR Archive leaves Files untouched.

So, in your Case: **Check your ISO**