# A media driver your computer needs is missing - Installing windows 10 from bootable usb

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, installation

I am installing windows 10 on a completely new computer. I created the installation media drive using the windows media creation tool. When installing I get the error `A media driver your computer needs is missing.`

I've found in many places on the internet answes like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1042765/windows-10-installation-failure-due-to-missing-driver), but it doesn't seem to work for me. Other pages indicate to use the windows media creation tool instead of another method but that is the way I'm doing it. I can't find a solution for this.

I don't know if it's related but I'm using an amd ryzen 2600x microprocessor into a tomahawk b450 motherboard.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some advice which might help:

- Install using a USB2 port.
- Ensure that the installation media is consistent with your hardware as regarding
  32/64 bitness. Download it again just in case.
- Check BIOS settings: Try to disable *Legacy USB* and *Legacy BIOS*
  and enable *AHCI*.
  You might try flipping *SATA Mode* (IDE/SATA), and the same for USB 3.0 support.
- Use RUFUS to create the boot media instead of Media Creation Tool
  ([tutorial](https://appuals.com/how-to-create-windows-10-bootable-usb-using-rufus/)).

Comment: I made it work using a 2.0 usb port and a different usb.

Comment: The problem for me was not USB2 vs USB3, but that I had to create a USB stick with GPT partition map and FAT32 file system. Rufus did the job for me.